# Undefined variable Laravel (strange case)

Tags: laravel

I am m having this annoying problem. Can anyone give a hand to sort out it? I read all posts and I cannot find the solution.

This is my controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Post;
use App\RegisteredCourse;

class DashboardsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexA()
    {

        return view('dashboards.admin-dashboard');
    }

    public function indexS()
    {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $courses = DB::table('registered__courses')->select('user_id')->where('user_id', '=', $id)->count();
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('dashboards.student-dashboard', compact('id', 'courses', 'posts'));
    }

    public function indexT()
    {

        return view('dashboards.teacher-dashboard');
    }
}
```

This is a fragment of the blade view. The name of the view is dashboards.student-dashboard

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title">Posts</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">
          <!-- Post -->
          <!--forEACH-->
          @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <div class="post">
              <div class="user-block">
                <span class="username">
                  <a href="#">{{$post->title}} | {{$post->author}}</a>
                </span>
                <span class="description">{{optional($post->created_at)->format('d-m-Y')}}</span>
              </div>
              <!-- /.user-block -->
              <p>
                {{$post->content}}
              </p>
            </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And these are the routes

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard',], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', 'DashboardsController@indexA')->name('dashboards.indexA');
    Route::get('/teacher', 'DashboardsController@indexT')->name('dashboards.indexT');
    Route::get('/student', 'DashboardsController@indexS')->name('dashboards.indexS');
});
```

I tried to pass al the variable to the view and I always have the same problem. ("Undefined variable").It seems like blocked the possibility to pass variable to the blade view.

What I did before:

1-dd($posts) It does not working, it appears the exception "Undefined variable: posts".
2- I remove the whole content of the blade file and I tried with a simple varible and it stills appearing the exception "Undefined variable".
3- I ran php artisan view:clear and restarted the server.

Any sugestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Plz post that fragment view's filename

Comment: Only `indexS()` is returning a view with variable, do the same un the other methods.

Comment: undefined variable in what? it will tell you what file and what line ... this sounds like you are guessing at the error, which should never be the case

Comment: Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\laragon\www\hr-english\resources\views\dashboards\student-dashboard.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return view('dashboards.student-dashboard', compact('id', 'courses', 'posts'));
```

try

```
return view('dashboards.student-dashboard', ['id'=>$id, 'courses'=>$courses, 'posts'=>$posts]);
```